# How to insert data into database in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I am new in this work I have created simple form in view folder like this:

```html
 <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <table>
                <tr>
                 <td>Book Title</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="title" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                 <td>Book Author</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="author" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                 <td>Book Image</td>
                    <td><input type="file" name="image" /></td>
                </tr>
               
                <tr>
                 <td>Book Description</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="content" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" /></td>
                </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
```

and i receive form data in controller like this:

```html
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

 
 public function index()
     {
      $this->load->view('insert/post');
            
           $title = $this->input->post('title');
           $author = $this->input->post('author');
           $image = $this->input->post('image');
           $content = $this->input->post('content');
                               
     }
    
  }
```

but how to insert these data into database kindly help with simple codes.

Comment: please do not ask questions just asking for someone to code for you. there are many, many tutorials out there on google that will allow you to write simple. then, come here asking for help, if the code you wrote doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go

> application/controllers/Welcome.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {


    public function index()
    {   
        // If you have post data...
        if (!empty($_POST)) {
            $title = $this->input->post('title');
            $author = $this->input->post('author');
            $image = $this->input->post('image');
            $content = $this->input->post('content');
            // Checking if everything is there
            if ($title && $author && $image && $content) {
                // Loading model
                $this->load->model('exemple_model');
                $data = array(
                    'title' => $title,
                    'author' => $author,
                    'image' => $image,
                    'content' => $content
                );

                // Calling model
                $id = $this->exemple_model->insert($data);

                // You can do something else here
            }
        }
        // Loading view
        $this->load->view('insert/post');                       
    }

}
```

> application/models/Exemple_model.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Exemple_model extends CI_Model {


    public function insert($data) {
        // Inserting into your table
        $this->db->insert('MyTable', $data);
        // Return the id of inserted row
        return $idOfInsertedData = $this->db->insert_id();
    }

}
```

Comment: I did like this but data still not inserting in to database,

Comment: Well, you must be doing something wrong, CodeIgniter displays an error when your sql query is wrong. What's your complete code ? You never call a model in your snippet

Comment: I tried same as you defined:
<?php 

class Insert extends CI_Model {
    
    public function form($data) {
        
        $this->db->insert('bookdata', $data);
        
        return $idOfInsertedData = $this->db->insert_id();
    }
}

Comment: Are you using what i gave you ? If so, make sure every vars are filled with a value in the controller, var_dump them if necessary

Comment: Yes i am using which you gave me, and every vars are filled with a value in controller which are getting from a form.

Comment: Try to echo something just before loading model to be sure that the condition is valid

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->query(
    'INSERT INTO tbl (a, b, c, d) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)',
    array($a, $b, $c, $d)
);
```

or

```
$this->db->insert('tbl', array($a, $b, $c, $d));
```

Get last insert ID:

```
$idOfInsertedData = $this->db->insert_id();
```

Comment: but how to send these form values to model ? where i will run this insert query.

Comment: @ZubairAli just place this code into your model